# Cell reference changes for excel macro

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I worked with some collaboraters on the site a couple of months ago to perfect the following code, however trying to re-trace my steps in respect to cell references is proving difficult. To clarify - all that's changed is the following cell references below.

Essentially:

1. Column C has now changed to column J
2. Column R has now changed to column O
3. Column S has now changed to column P
4. Column T has now changed to column Q

But for the life of me I can't work out where these cell references take effect in the code.

```
Sub Display()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DISPLAY")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("REPORT_DOWNLOAD")

Dim arr_1 As Variant, arr_2 As Variant, arr_result As Variant
arr_1 = ws1.Range("C2:C" & ws2.Range("L" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value2
arr_2 = ws2.Range("E2:L" & ws2.Range("E" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value2

ReDim arr_result(LBound(arr_2) To UBound(arr_2), 1 To 3)

Dim i As Long, j As Long

For i = LBound(arr_1, 1) To UBound(arr_1, 1)
    For j = LBound(arr_2, 1) To UBound(arr_2, 1)

        If arr_1(i, 1) = arr_2(j, 1) Then
            'use this if you're handling numbers
            arr_result(i, 1) = arr_result(i, 1) + arr_2(j, 5)
            arr_result(i, 2) = arr_result(i, 2) + arr_2(j, 4)
            arr_result(i, 3) = arr_result(i, 3) + arr_2(j, 8)
        End If

    Next j
Next i

ws1.Cells(2, 18).Resize(UBound(arr_result, 1), 3).Value2 = arr_result

End Sub
```

Comment: If possible could you also explain how the cells are being referenced (for MY future reference haha)

Comment: When you populate an array from `E2:L?` the resulting arrays x and y index will always start at `arr_2(1,1)` refering to `E2`, and `arr_2(2,1)` refering to `E3`, but `arr_2(1,2)` refers to `F2`. So you got to work out the correct Y indexes for those columns to work with them

Comment: @JvdV this is where I'm getting confused, `arr_result(i, 1) = arr_result(i, 1) + arr_2(j, 5)` what cell does this currently point to?

Comment: Sorry, but your question does not make sense in the way you asked it... That `i` may be anything in the range of 1 (array rows) and number of rows. What @JvdV mentioned, you must extrapolate.. About your question, it can be translated like this: `arr_result` is abstract at that moment. It only has rows and columns. It becomes an Excel range only after being copied in sheet `ws1`.  `arr_2(j, 5)` means a row of the 5th column (J). But that workbook "changed" by itself? If not, you must learn VBA and remake the code according to your reality. When you will have a piece of code, post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you want to adapt the macro to changed column-wise layout of your worksheet?

There is some missing information in your question:

- which worksheet changed? (only change corresponding references)
- did the order of columns change? (your arrays definitely rely on a fixed order of  columns)

You have two places where you interact with Excel columns (shown below). This is where you need to make your changes.

1. When assigning values to your arrays:

Columns **C through L**:

*(presumably this requires your C->J change, so **"C2:C" => "J2:J"**)*

```
    arr_1 = ws1.Range("C2:C" & ws2.Range("L" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value2
```

Columns **E through L**:

```
    arr_2 = ws2.Range("E2:L" & ws2.Range("E" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value2
```

2. When outputting values to ws1 (**Columns R through T** - that's columns 18 and 2 additional columns after the resize, if I count correctly):

*(Presumably this requires your R->O, S->P, T->Q changes, so **18 => 15**)*

```
    ws1.Cells(2, 18).Resize(UBound(arr_result, 1), 3).Value2 = arr_result
```

Comment: Works perfectly! very grateful for your level of detail!